# Securing web application used for core business process

Tags: apache-2.2, security, hosting

I am writing an application which will be used for our core business workflows (client registration and management etc).

I have partners and employees who are spread across the globe, so I want to make them be able to log in and use the application, over the internet - but I want to bar everyone else (including bots and indexers) from accessing my web application.

I am using Apache as the web server, and I am using xxx.mydomainname.com to access my web application

How can I secure the application so that only the following entities can access the application:

```
1. Machines on my company LAN (windows networked computers)
2. Specific machines connecting across the internet
```

I specifically, do not want the pages indexed and archived by any bots etc, since the pages contain sensitive client information etc.

How can I secure my web application to BAN all access and permit only those specified above?

Comment: By making everyone log in.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I wanted to prevent brute force attacks by serving a 404 page when any of the unauthorized machine/network combo tries to access a page (I'm aware of IP spoofing, but hopefully, this is not in the arsenal of the novice/average/wannabe hacker)

Comment: You prevent brute force attacks with strong passwords and rate limiting. The problem is that you have no way of knowing where a valid user will be logging in from. It could be from their office or an airport lounge in Dubai.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks for your comment; its made me realize that perhaps I should have framed the question differently. Strong passwords, rate logging and required logging will solve most of the problems relating to bots etc - however, that solution does not prevent an employee to login into the application from a wine bar (for example), and leave client details exposed to the world, so I think the problem decomposes into one of restricting access by IP address (or something similar)

Comment: Why is it a problem to log in from a wine bar?